# ¿Por qué no se usa el subjuntivo en "No estoy seguro que entiendo"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, subjuntivo

En esta frase:

> No estoy seguro que entiendo.

¿Por qué no se usa el subjuntivo con el segundo verbo? Pensaba que se usa el subjuntivo cuando el primer verbo expresa duda, como en *no estoy seguro*.

Comment: Bueno, en principio, es un ejemplo de *queísimo*, hace falta un *de* entre *seguro* y *que*.

Comment: Yo diría *No estoy seguro de **si** entiendo.* Debería quizá ir en subjuntivo pero la regla no es tan sencilla.

Comment: Otra posibilidad es usar el infinitivo: *No estoy seguro de entender/de estar entendiendo.*

Comment: Creo que diría *No entendí muy bien, no entendí bien bien*, or *no entendí del todo*.

Answer (score 2):

Most people would find ❌*"No estoy seguro que **entiendo**"* ungrammatical or unidiomatic.

*"No estoy seguro de que **entienda**"* and *"No estoy seguro de que **haya** entendido"*, both using the subjunctive, would be right.

To avoid 1st / 3rd person confusion (where the subjunctive form is the same for both) it is also common to switch to infinitive: "No estoy seguro de **entender**", "No estoy seguro de **haber** entendido", *"No estoy seguro de **estar** entendiendo"*.

Also, please notice that in all cases it is said *"estar seguro **de** (something)"*, where something is replaced with whatever you are not sure of: *seguro de (todo esto), seguro de (entender bien), seguro de (que haya comprendido), seguro de (lo que ha pasado)*...

Comment: It can be idiomatic, but it requires a particular context: http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro/ARCHIVO-Foro/No%20creo%20que-subjuntivo%20o%20indicativo.htm